# Flexbox Scrolling Parent, Children 100% Height

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm working on an application that contains a custom calendar.  The calendar is styled with Flexbox (all the building / date logic is handled with React).

The calendar is functioning great, but I'm having a styling problem I'm not sure how to solve.

When lots of events are added in a particular week, I'd like the `week` div to `overflow: auto;` (show a scrollbar) so that you can view all of the events.

The problem I am having is a height issue on the `day` divs.  I don't have a fixed height on the parent (`week` div) since I am using flexbox with `flex: 1;` to fill the space.  How can I get the children (`day` divs) to use the entire height of the overflowing parent (`week` div)?

I'd prefer to have a CSS only solution that works cross-browser.

Sample CodePen Here:
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jLQyxX?editors=0100

HTML:

```
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="day">6</div>
    <div class="day">7</div>
    <div class="day">8</div>
    <div class="day">
      <div>This</div>
      <div>Border</div>
      <div>Doesn't</div>
      <div>Scale</div>
      <div>Correctly</div>
      <div>(Scroll Down)</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">10</div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
}

.calendar {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 15px;
}

.week {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.day {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}
```

Comment: At all possible to put a scrollbar in the `day` element?

Comment: Alternative is to fake the borders of the day elements by using a CSS background gradient and remove the outlines from them altogether. That's the only thing stopping your `day` elements from looking like they are full height.

Comment: @Adam I did experiment with that at first when running into my posted issue.  Unfortunately, it doesn't work for my case as the events can run across several days (similar to FullCalendar https://fullcalendar.io/)

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for sharing the link - I was expecting that there would be no easy CSS solution - aside from some creative "hacking" to get the desired look.  I did quite a lot of searching on the web for this issue and that link never came up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible solution would be to add a wrapper `wrap` between the `week` and `day`
<sub>This works on Chrome/Firefox/Edge, IE though, has some issue I am looking into, and don't have Safari to test it on.</sub>

[Updated codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LjXgqK)

Stack snippet

```css
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
}

.calendar {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin: 15px;
  height: calc(100vh - 30px);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.week {
  flex: 1;
  min-height: 20%;
  overflow: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.week .wrap {
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.day {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
  outline: 1px dotted red;
}

.week:nth-child(even) .day {
  background: lightgray
}
```

```html
<div class="calendar">
  <div class="week">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="day">1</div>
    <div class="day">2</div>
    <div class="day">3</div>
    <div class="day">4</div>
    <div class="day">5</div> 
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="day">6</div>
    <div class="day">7</div>
    <div class="day">8</div>
    <div class="day">
      <div>9</div>
      <div>&nbsp;</div>
      <div>This</div>
      <div>Border</div>
      <div>Doesn't</div>
      <div>Scale</div>
      <div>Correctly</div>
      <div>(Scroll Down)</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
      <div>...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="day">10</div> 
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="day">11</div>
    <div class="day">12</div>
    <div class="day">13</div>
    <div class="day">14</div>
    <div class="day">15</div> 
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="day">16</div>
    <div class="day">17</div>
    <div class="day">18</div>
    <div class="day">19</div>
    <div class="day">20</div> 
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="week">
    <div class="wrap">
    <div class="day">21</div>
    <div class="day">22</div>
    <div class="day">23</div>
    <div class="day">24</div>
    <div class="day">25</div> 
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Since your main *grid* keeps an equal size per day (use `flex: 1` to fill remaining space), another option would be to use absolute positioning for the `week` and `day`, and then make `day` a flex container to handle its content.

Comment: This works quite well for my use case - thank you.  I did test Safari and saw that it didn't work well but it was on an old version and I don't have a more updated Mac to test on easily. Fortunately, this is for an internal application and we don't have any Safari users.

Answer (score -1):

The best way to do it is moving the `overflow: auto` from `.week` to `.day`